# Generating a new variable in R where the nth observation depends on the n-1th observation of another column

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a data frame that look something like this:

```
>df
city  year  ceep
  1    1      1
  1    2      1
  1    3      0
  1    4      1
  1    5      0
  2    1      0
  2    2      1
  2    3      1
  2    4      0
  2    5      1
  3    1      1
  3    2      0
  3    3      1
  3    4      0
  3    5      1
```

Now I want to create a new variable 'veep' that depends on the values of 'city' and 'ceep' from different rows. For instance,

```
veep=1 if ceep[_n-1]=1 & city=city[_n-1]
veep=1 if ceep[_n+2]=1 & ceep[_n+3]=1 & city=city[_n+3]
```

where `n` is the row of observation. I'm not sure how to translate these conditions into R language. I guess where I'm having trouble is choosing the row of observation. I'm thinking of a code somewhere along the lines of:

```
df$veep[df$ceep(of the n-1th observation)==1 & city==city(n-1th observ.)] <- 1
df$veep[df$ceep(of the n+2th observation)==1 & df$ceep(of the n+3th observation)==1 &
city==city(n+3th observ.)] <- 1

#note: what's in parentheses is just to demonstrate where I'm having trouble
```

Can anyone provide help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop like this

```
df$veep <- 0   

for (i in seq(nrow(df))){
 if (i > 1 & i < nrow(df)-2){
    if (df[i-1,"ceep"]==1 & df[i-1,"city"] == df[i,"city"])
       df[i,"veep"] <- 1
 }
}
```

Comment: What about row `nrow(df) - 1`?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to write out your logical steps. Note the use of `idx` to index the vectors. That was necessary to avoid out-of-range indexes.

```
idx <- seq_len(nrow(df))

# Set a default value for the new variable
df$veep <- NA
```

Your first set of logical criteria cannot be applied to the first row of `df`, since the index `n - 1` would be `0`, and this is not a valid row index. So, use `tail(*, -1)` to pick out all but the first entries of `veep` and `city` and use `head(*, -1)` to pick out all but the last of `ceep` and `city`.

```
df[tail(idx, -1), "veep"] <- ifelse(
  head(df$ceep, -1) == 1 &
  tail(df$city, -1) == head(df$city, -1),
  1, tail(df$veep, -1))
```

Your next set of criteria cannot be applied to the last three rows of `df`, since `n + 3` would then be an invalid index. So use the `head` and `tail` functions again. One tricky part is the fact that the first `ceep` statement is based on `n + 2`, not `n + 3`, so that a combination of `head` and `tail` is required.

```
df[head(idx, -3), "veep"] <- ifelse(
  head(tail(df$ceep, -2), -1) == 1 &
  tail(df$ceep, -3) == 1 &
  head(df$city, -3) == tail(df$city, -3),
  1, head(df$veep, -3))

> df$veep
 [1] NA  1  1 NA  1 NA NA  1  1 NA NA  1 NA  1 NA
```

Comment: pretty , but isn't a little hard for a newbie?

Comment: @agstudy, You're likely right. Perhaps some 'splaining is in order.

Comment: @econlearner, I've commented the code above to explain the `head` and `tail` bits.